# How to automatically update object reference

Tags: c#, .net

Given this example code:

```
MyTable myTable = new MyTable();
MyTableClient1 foo= new MyTableClient1(myTable);
MyTableClient2 bar= new MyTableClient2(myTable);
MyTableClient3 baz= new MyTableClient3(myTable);
... and so on
```

So you can see that I create an instance of MyTable and I pass it to other objects that stores it internally, they use it and they probably pass it to other objects.

So the reference to myTable spread through many many objects in my runtime environment

Now come the problem: I have to update myTable, but I have a method that gives me a new updated MyTable object. Check the following:

```
myTable= MyTableProvider.getUpdated(myTable);
```

Of cource this statement is useless because all the references to myTable inside foo, bar, etc, etc remain tied to the old MyTable object...

I need a way to tell to c#: "All the existing references to this object have to be updated to another object!"

Is there a way to do this? I can't think to manually replace objects inside foo, bar, baz, etc.

Comment: What does `getUpdated` do?

Comment: Not an answer but the best idea would be to avoid this... Either your TableClient concept or your update method is wrong. Or both.

Comment: getUpdated  returns a reference to a new object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1:**
One way to do this would be to use a wrapper class:

```
class TableWrapper {
        public TableWrapper(MyTable table) {this.Table = table}
        public MyTable Table {get; set;}
}
```

then your code would be:

```
MyTable myTable = new MyTable();
TableWrapper wrapped = new TableWrapper(myTable)
MyTableClient1 foo= new MyTableClient1(wrapped);
MyTableClient2 bar= new MyTableClient2(wrapped);

wrapped.Table= MyTableProvider.getUpdated(myTable);
```

This way, your client receives the wrapped object and uses arg.Table instead of just arg; you then modify the property of wrapped and your clients are now updated.

**Approach 2:** EDIT: below does not work since refs cannot be stored as object properties. Not deleting for archive purposes.
Use C#'s "ref" keyword.

Modify MyTableClient's constructor to accept a ref MyTable instead of just a MyTable. Then pass the table in by doing

```
MyTable myTable = new MyTable();
MyTableClient1 foo= new MyTableClient1(ref myTable);
MyTableClient2 bar= new MyTableClient2(ref myTable);
```

as long as MyTableClient does not copy the data but uses the original reference, changing myTable to be the updated table will cause the changes to be reflected in the table clients.

Comment: Unfortunately, this wouldn't solve the problem of having to update multiple `wrapped.Table` references

Comment: thanks Sebastian, made that change. Camilo -- since C# passes objects by reference, and not by value, will updating the single wrapped.Table not reflect across all the table references that have been passed to clients?

Comment: That would depend on what `MyTableProvider.getUpdated` does, whether it updates the same reference or just creates a new object

Comment: Sure; let's say getUpdated returns a reference to a new object (let's call this reference U, which points to the new, updated table). The old table is at reference O. wrapped is passed into the table clients, which access wrapped.Table whenever they need to interact with the table. when wrapped.Table is changed to point from O to U, subsequent accesses to wrapped.Table from the clients will yield a reference to U. I believe that this accomplishes OP's intended effect.

Comment: You should add a line for `bar` as well to show if your wrapper would work.

Comment: thank you Harshita for the answer.

yes getUpdated returns a reference to a new object.


Approach 1 is acceptable but not so good for me.


Approach 2 would be very good but it dont works :(

I store myTable inside foo this way:

MyTableClient1 foo= new MyTableClient1(ref myTable);


then I update the reference in this way:

myTable= MyTableProvider.getUpdated(myTable);


but the reference inside foo remain tied to the old object

Comment: Hi Tara, could you provide the code for the MyTableClient constructor? What do you do with the reference to the table? For the "ref" approach to work, you would want to store a property inside the table client of type `ref myTable` instead of just of type `myTable`.

Comment: @HarshitaGupta
MyTableClient  constructor simply store the reference in a public property.

Other methods of MyTableClient  read and write MyTable properties.

I cant compile MyTableClient with "private ref  MyTable _prgTab;"
 due to Syntax error "(" expected...

Comment: On reading further, I see the error in my original conception of Approach 2. Since what you're essentially looking for is a global variable, C# requires you to wrap the variable in a class in order to be able to access it globally (so approach 1). If you are certain that you want to avoid this, you could try the not-recommended usage of pointers (unsafe C#) here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-types.

Comment: May I ask what about Approach 1 doesn't work for you?

Comment: @HarshitaGupta

Approach 1 require a bit more refactoring in my code..
Anyway it's perfectly fine!
Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the full property.

```
    MyTableClient1 foo;
    MyTableClient2 bar;
    MyTableClient3 baz;

    private MyTable _myTable;
    public MyTable myTable
    {
        get { return _myTable; }
        set 
            { 
                foo = new MyTableClient1(value);
                bar = new MyTableClient2(value);
                baz = new MyTableClient3(value);

                _myTable = value;  
            }
    }
```